# Php function do not work with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have some php and javascript, everythings work and I do not get any error message. I can post data without any error to database. And everythings looks good but I cannot use some function in php.

Example.

I have a textarea and I send its data with ajax to a php file. In php file a need to use str_replace function. I can insert data to database in same php file without any error  but the function that I try to use like str_replace or mysqli_real_escape_string, etc. do not work.

What would be the reason?

Here codes.

```
    $(".editBoxButton").click(function(){

        var yazi = jQuery('#editInput').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST' ,
                url : 'ajax/editEntry.php',
                    data: {
                    text: yazi,
                    },
                success : function(d){ 
                alert(d);
                location.reload();  //refresh
                }
            });

    });
```

ajax/editEntry.php

```
<?php

$yeniyazi=$_POST['text'];   
$yeniyazi = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $yeniyazi);

$s=$yeniyazi;

echo json_encode($s);

?>
```

in the alert, I get still \n. it does not replaced.

**I do not get any error. only str_replace do not work that is my problem. expect str_replace, it works properly.**

Comment: make sure you use double quotes for special characters as \n (happened to me). I know your answer has double quotes, just in case you didn't copy-paste

Comment: json_encode turns an array/object into a string. You seem to be working on a string already, so there is no need for a json_encode.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just do:

`$yeniyazi = nl2br($yeniyazi);`

If you really want to manually replace, use regex.

`$yeniyazi = preg_replace("/\r?\n/s", "<br />", $yeniyazi);`

Comment: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) also has the benefit that it will handle different forms of new lines (i.e. \r\n, \n\r, \n, and \r)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to escape the \ with another one or use singlequotes instead.

```
$val = str_replace("\\n" , "<br>", $val);
```

Or you can do it in a single line like this :

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(nl2br($_POST['text']));
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this example help you:

```
<?php
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);

 // Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

// Outputs: apearpearle pear
// For the same reason mentioned above
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have problem with `\n` using in javascript and PHP.

Current Env.:

- PHP 5.3.10
- Javascript
- XHTML 1.0

The problem:

```
....
if (rowcount == 5) {
    openShipments += '\n';
    rowcount = 0;
}
....
```

It works when using `\\n` bellow:

```
....
if (rowcount == 5) {
    openShipments += '\\n';
    rowcount = 0;
}
....
```